# How do I get/set the selectable playback rates in UWP MediaPlayerElement?

Tags: uwp

Currently, I don't see a way to get or set the list of playback rates provided by MediaTransportControls.IsPlaybackRateEnabled = true. Does anyone know how to get, or set, the list of provided values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MediaPlayerElement` does not provide an alternative list of playback rates, only provides buttons that can be used to adjust the playback rate

*Set `MediaTransportControls.IsPlaybackRateButtonVisible` as `True`*

After turning on `MediaPlayerElement.IsPlaybackRateEnabled`, the player allows users to adjust the playback rate, and their processing logic has been encapsulated in `MediaTransportControls`.

If you want to manually adjust the playback rate of `MediaPlayerElement`, you can use the following methods:

```cs
_playRate = 1.5;
if (mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer != null)
{
    var session = mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession;
    session.PlaybackRate = _playRate;
}
```

If you want to add custom control in `MediaTransportControls`, such as providing a `ComboBox` to let users choose a suitable playback rate, you can refer to this document to create your own custom controls:

- [Create custom transport controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls)